# INDEX MATCH based on multiple criteria. One is FIND and other is Max date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hoping for some help with a formula. I haven't been able to find an answer for this particular combination of issues.

I want to create an INDEX MATCH lookup based on three criteria:

1. Normal text lookup
2. Text lookup possibly within a larger string of text (used FIND for this)
3. Latest date

I can't figure out how to work in the third point. Here's my formula that captures the first two:

=INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(1,($A$8=$A$2:$A$4)*(FIND(B8,$B$2:$B$4)>0),0))

See image below. I would want the result in cell C8 to be "Q3" because that row has the later date and fulfills the other two criteria.

[image: Excel Formula Pic]

Answer (score 1):

This can be made simpler with a few changes.

If you change column C to a number, and just use formatting to add the "Q",
you can then use excel's MaxIFs function.

So then, assuming the lookup is based on A8 and B8 , we can seek the max 'Quarter?' field ( or date )  where it matches those criterea, and better still, the syntax is much easier to read ( for example, we can find 'B' with a Wildcard. )

```
=MAXIFS(C1:C4,B1:B4,"*B*",A1:A4,A9)
```

[edit]  - here's the example sheet :
http://www.instantexcel.com/downloads/stackexchange/64235227.xlsx

See attached image for a better example. [Worksheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5W8O.jpg)

[edit 2] :: - I got a warning message from Stack Overflow not to reply to the message, so I'm adding it here.

Are saying you're unable to change the data in the sheet (add a column /  format / create a synthetic key by concatenation etc?

You could combine a maxifs, to get
A -  The latest data in column D, where Columns A and B are matched ( CTG and DETAIL )
B -  Use the result of (A)  - which I assume would NOT be a duplicate/reoccuring value?

I'd use example :

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$4,MATCH(MAXIFS(D1:D4,B1:B4,"*"&B9&"*",A1:A4,A9),D1:D4,0))
```

Comment: You could change `"*B*"` to `"*"&B8&"*"` to include the cell-reference.

Comment: Thanks for this! MAXIF with the format changes is definitely more elegant. The tricky part is (a) the period column is actually typically input as "2017Q1" and can't be changed and (b) processing date doesn't necessarily tie nicely with the period. Ideally, I'd like to find the most recent/last occurrence based on the date.  I worked out a formula using LOOKUP that pulls the last row based on A8 and B8, but it wouldn't work if the data was sorted or input such that the most recent occurrence isn't last anymore...

Comment: @Tantomile02  - I've edited my post with an alternative - hopefully this helps! It's not as clean, but hopefully it's still relatively easy to follow if you break down the individual steps.